# When All images loaded, execute a code

Tags: javascript, jquery

**add.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("img").load(function() {
     alert("all images loaded");
});
</script>
<?php 
function resim1(){
?>
<img height="150" weight="150" src="http://uyarer.com/linux/deneme.png"/>
<?php
}
?>

<?php 
function resim2(){
?>
<img height="150" weight="150" src="http://hunturk.net/resim-cnNtL2dhbGVyaS9iYXlyYWsvZTc4M2NlYzRlYi5qcGc=-1024-768.png"/>
<?php
}
?>
<?php 
 resim1();
 resim2();
?>
```

when executed this code.,the jquery alert for every loaded images.
I imported this php page another php with ajax.

For example

1.jpg   alert > loaded
2.jpg   alert > loaded

but i want

1.jpg
2.jpg
       alert > all images loaded

i guess i change this code

```
$(**"img"**).load(function() {
 alert("all images loaded");
```

});

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice to listen to the window.(on)load event?

Answer (score 3):

Load event won't always fire when images are cached. There is a [jquery plugin](https://gist.github.com/268257) to address this issue.

Answer (score 3):

```
var imgNum=$('img').length;
$('img').load(function(){
    if(!--imgNum){alert('All images loaded')}
})
```

I think this code can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
var imgSize = 0;
var loaded = 0;
var _tim = 0;
$(document).ready(function()
{
 imgSize = $('img').size();
 $('img').load(function() {
   loaded++;
   clearTimeout(_tim);
  _tim =   setTimeout(function() { if(imgSize == loaded) { alert('all images are loaded'); }, 200);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var imagesPre = new Array;
var success = new Array;

$('img').each(function(){
  imagesPre.push(this.src);
});

for (i = 0; i < imagesPre.length; i++) {
    (function(path, success) {
        image = new Image();
        image.onload = function() {
          success.resolve();
        };
        image.src = path;
    })(imagesPre[i], success[i] = $.Deferred());
}

$.when.apply($, success).done(function() {
  alert("All image!");
});
```